# How to properly make a dynamic command-line menu?

Tags: c, data-structures, menu, submenu

More precisely.. How do I add a "go back to main menu" function as all other softwares and games have?

```
void showMenu()
{
    puts( "1. Create school\n" 
           "2. Add room\n" 
           "3.Add student to room\n"
           "4.Find student\n"
           "5. Show students in room\n"
           "\n" "6. Exit");
}


int main()
{
    clrscr();

    studentList *foundStudent;

    int input;
    showMenu();

    while( scanf("%d", &input) )
    {   

        if(input == 6)
        {
            periods("Exiting");
            break;
        }

        if(input == 1)
        {
            school *school;
            school = createSchool();
        }

        if(input == 2)
        {
            int room, roomNr;
            printf("Enter room Nr. and Class:");
            scanf("%d %d", &room, &roomNr);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Anything I attempted didn't work and just created more redundancy, never expected how `goto` can be so confusing.

Although `switch` makes more sense, I don't believe it fixes my problem.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("1. Create school\n");
    printf("2. Add room\n");
    printf("3. Add student to room\n");
    printf("4. Find student\n");
    printf("5. Show students in room\n");

    printf("\n");
    printf("6. Exit");`  the function: `printf()` is very expensive in CPU cycles.  Suggest: `puts( "1. Create school\n"
         "2. Add room\n"
         "3. Add student to room\n"
         "4. Find student\n"
         "5. Show students in room\n"
         "\n"
         "6. Exit");`

Comment: I thinks it's time to review how `scanf` works. You have to pass the *address* of `input`, so `scanf("%d", &input)`, and the second call passed no addresses at all. Then, the `while` loop. Check out what is returned by function `scanf`, in that case it should return `1` to be of use to you. Also, `if(input == 6);` won't need that `;` semicolon. Also `school *school;` goes out of scope. And so on, the code is riddled with errors.

Comment: regarding: `while( scanf("%d", input) )`  The `scanf()` family of functions can also return EOF, so this statement can 'succeed' when EOF is encountered.  Suggest: `while( scanf("%d", input)  == 1 )`

Comment: Sorry! this was mistake on my part. ```input``` was a ```char```  array and I just switched it to ```int``` without modifying the rest of the code, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you mean by ```school* school;``` going out of scope?

Comment: regarding: `school *school;
            school = createSchool();`   this hints that `school` is a 'typedef' for some struct.  It is a very poor programing practice to name a local variable the same as a typedef name.

Comment: regarding: `again: ;
            printf("Enter room Nr. and Class:");
            int ok = scanf("%d %d");
            if(ok != 2)
            {
                printf("Error parsing info, please try again!");
                goto again;`  1) write a `do ... while();` loop and eliminate that label and goto()`  2) the call to `scanf()` is missing the addresses of the variables to receive the data input

Comment: Suggest, rather than the many code blocks, beginning with statements like: `if(input == 6);` it would avoid the retesting of the variable 'input' over and over, to use a `switch( input ) { case 1: ..,, break; ... default: ... break; }` code block

Comment: @user3629249 about the ```typedefs```.. I see, thanks! this how we did it in all of our assignments and in class works.  Sorry about the mistakes in the code, I hastily asked this question without making sure everything else is in order. and in the ```do ..while()``` I write some kind of exit value? this way I will return to the outside loop?

Comment: I mean that `school *school;` goes out of scope - meaning no longer accessible - outside of the conditional code block `if(input == 1) {...}`.

Comment: I see, so I should declare it outside  the ```if()```  block?

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error parsing info, please try again!");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  (note: the `scanf()` family does not set `errno` when some input format conversion specifier fails)  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "scanf to read ??? and ??? failed" );`  which probably should be followed by cleanup and a call to `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `do ..while()`  inside the parens should be the condition as to why the code should stay in the loop

Comment: the type of error I'm avoiding here is if a user inputted 3 integers separated by spaces, when my ```scanf()``` is only supposed to accept 2.

Comment: the third integer will still be in `stdin`  So the third integer will be read at the call to `scanf()` for the menu input.  What happens next will depend on the value of that third integer.  Suggest before calling `scanf()` to empty `stdin` via something like: `int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != '\n' && ch != EOF ){;}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.
The solution for this problem was simply making a "menu within a menu" kind of, I did use some `goto`s but as far as commandline menu goes, this may be all.

```
#define clrscr() printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J")

void periods(char* message)
{   
    const int trigger = 500; // ms
    const int numDots = 3;

    while (1) 
    {
        // Return and clear with spaces, then return and print prompt.
        printf("\r%*s\r%s", sizeof(message) - 1 + numDots, "", message);
        fflush(stdout);

        // Print numDots number of dots, one every trigger milliseconds.
        for (int i = 0; i < numDots; i++) 
        {
            usleep(trigger * 1000);
            fputc('.', stdout);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        break;
    }
}

void showmenu()
{
    clrscr();
    puts("1. New Game\n"
         "2. Load Game\n"
         "3. Credits\n\n"
         "4. Exit\n" );

}

int checkString(char *str)
{
    int status = 0;
    int ln = strlen(str);

    for(int i = 0; i < ln; i++)
    {
        if(isdigit( str[i] ) )
        status = 1; 
        break;
    }

    return status; 
}

int main(){

    char choice; 

    clrscr();
    int status, isNum = -101;
    char *name, *buffer, YN;

    showmenu();
    while(1)
    {
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
       if( isdigit(choice) )
       {
           break;     
       }
       else
       {
           fflush(stdin);
           printf("Please only enter numbers!\n");
           sleep(1);
           showmenu();
        }
     }

    do{ 


        switch(choice)
        {
            case '1':
            {
                createG:;
                clrscr();

                printf("Enter name or press 0 to return\n");
                scanf("%s", buffer);
                status = checkString(buffer);
                if(status == 1)
                {
                    clrscr();
                    break;
                }
                clrscr();       
                name = (char*)malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
                strcpy(name, buffer);
                printf("New game created, welocome %s!\n");
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    sleep(1);
                    printf("%d\n", i);
                }
                break;
            }

            case '2': 
            {
                int what;
                caseL:;
                clrscr();
                printf("No saves!\n Create new game? [Y/N] \n to return press 0\n");
                scanf(" %c", &YN);

                if(YN == 'N') what = 0;
                if(YN == '0') what = -1;
                if(YN == 'Y') what = 1;
                switch(YN)
                {
                    case 'N':
                    {
                        goto caseL;
                    }

                    case '0':
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    case 'Y':
                    {
                        choice = 1;
                        goto createG;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                break;
            }

            case '3':
            {
                periods("Hello World");
                break;
            }

            case '4': 
            {
                clrscr();
                periods("Goodbye");
                clrscr();
                exit(1);
            }

            default:
            {
                printf("Wrong input\n Try again");
                sleep(1);
                break; 
            }
        }

    }while(choice != -2);


    return 0;
}
```

This may still need a lot of error checking and handling for "unexpected" inputs but it answers the problem.